# android layout_gravity - how to align ad unit to bottom and place buttons just above the ad unit

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get the buttons and ad unit to be at the bottom of the screen, with the buttons directly above the ad unit. But the buttons are still in the middle of the page. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner_adview"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       >
       <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_use" 
            android:onClick="onUse" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_share" 
            android:onClick="onShare" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView
        android:id="@+id/banner_adview"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

from your `LineraLayout`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using setting your linear layout to be `android:layout_above="@+id/banner_adview"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    <include layout="@layout/buttons" />
  <com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView
    android:id="@+id/banner_adview"
    android:layout_width="320dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

> create button xml and inside main layout include it

buttons.xml

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   >
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_use" 
        android:onClick="onUse" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_share" 
        android:onClick="onShare" />
</LinearLayout>
```